# gsl Error in inifinite integration interval. bad integrand behavior found. How to fix it?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, integration, gsl

I'm getting the following error message after trying to do the a numerical integration on a infinte interval [0,inf)  using  GSL in C.

```
gsl: qags.c:553: ERROR: bad integrand behavior found in the integration interval
Default GSL error handler invoked.
Command terminated by signal 6
```

Here is the function I'm integrating
$

```
double dI2dmu(double x, void * parametros){
  double *p,Ep,mu,M,T;  
  p=(double *) parametros;

  M=p[0];
  T=p[1];
  mu=p[2];

  Ep=sqrt(x*x+M*M);

  double fplus= -((exp((Ep - mu)/T)/(pow(1 + exp((Ep - mu)/T),2)*T) - exp((Ep + \
mu)/T)/(pow(1 + exp((Ep + mu)/T),2)*T))*pow(x,2))/(2.*Ep*pow(PI,2));
  return fplus;
}
```

And the code for the integration procedure

```
 params[0]=0.007683; //M
 params[1]=0.284000;// T
 params[2]=0.1;   //mu

    gsl_function dI2mu_u; 
    dI2mu_u.function = &dI2dmu;
    dI2mu_u.params = &params;
    gsl_integration_qagiu (&dI2mu_u, 0, 0, 1e-7, 100000,
             w, &resultTest2, &error1Test2);
```

The fucntion has the following aspect:

[image: Funcion im trying to integrate]Which, to my eyes, has a very well behavior. So, instead of performing an infinite integration, I perform the integration up to an upper limit that I consider rezonable, like in:

```
  gsl_function G;
 G.function = &dI2dmu;
 G.params = &params;

 gsl_integration_qags (&G, 0, 1e2*A, 0, 1e-7, 100000,
                    w, &result1, &error1);
```

Getting a result that agrees with the result of Mathematica for infinite integration

```
result definite up to 10*A        =  0.005065263943958745
result up to infinity             =  nan
Mathematica result up to infinity =  0.005065260000000000
```

But the GSL infinite integral keps being "nan". Any ideas? I thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You might want to replace `Ep = sqrt(x*x+M*M);` with `Ep = hypot(x,M)`.

Answer (score 2):

As @yonatan zuleta ochoa points out correctly, the problem is in `exp(t)/pow(exp(t)+1,2)`. `exp(t)` can overflow an ieee754 `DBL_MAX` for values of `t` as low as `nextafter(log(DBL_MAX), INFINITY)`, which is `~7.09783e2`.

When `exp(t) == INFINITY`,

```
exp(t)/pow(exp(t)+1,2) == ∞/pow(∞+1,2) == ∞/∞ == NAN
```

Yonatan's proposed solution is to use logarithms, which can be done as follows:

```
exp(t)/pow(exp(t)+1,2) == exp(log(exp(t)) - log(pow(exp(t)+1,2)))
                       == exp(t - 2*log(exp(t)+1))
                       == exp(t - 2*log1p(exp(t))) //<math.h> function avoiding loss of precision for log(exp(t)+1)) if exp(t) << 1.0
```

This is an entirely reasonable approach, avoiding `NAN` up to very high values of `t`. However, in your code, `t == (Ep ± mu)/T` can be `INFINITY` if `abs(T) < 1.0` for values of `x` close to `DBL_MAX`, even if `x` is *not* infinity. In this case, the subtraction `t - 2*log1p(exp(t))` turns into `∞ - ∞`, which is `NAN` again.

A different approach is to replace `exp(x)/pow(exp(x)+1,2)` with `1.0/(pow(exp(x)+1,2)*pow(exp(x), -1))` by dividing both denominator and numerator by `exp(x)` (which is not zero for any finite `x`). This simplifies to `1.0/(exp(x)+exp(-x)+2.0)`.

Here is an implementation of the function avoiding `NAN` for values of `x` up to and including `DBL_MAX`:

```
static double auxfun4(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
  return 1.0/(a*b+2.0+c*d);
}
double dI2dmu(double x, void * parametros)
{
  double *p = (double *) parametros;
  double invT = 1.0/p[1];
  double Ep = hypot(x, p[0]);
  double muexp = exp(p[2]*invT);
  double Epexp = exp(Ep*invT);
  double muinv = 1.0/muexp;
  double Epinv = 1.0/Epexp;
  double subterm = auxfun4(Epexp, muinv, Epinv, muexp);
  subterm -= auxfun4(Epexp, muexp, Epinv, muinv);
  double fminus = subterm*(x/Ep)*invT*(0.5/(M_PI*M_PI))*x;;
  return -fminus;
}
```

This implementation also uses `hypot(x,M)`, rather than `sqrt(x*x, M*M)`, and avoids calculating `x*x` by rearranging the order of multiplications/divisions to group `x/Ep` together. Since `hypot(x,M)` will be `abs(x)` for `abs(x) >> abs(M)`, the term `x/Ep` approaches `1.0` for large `x`.

Comment: Thank you so much @EOF. I think this will improve a lot my code

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that unlike Mathematica, C does not use arbitrary precision in computing. Then, at some point when Exp [Ep] is calculated numerical computation overflows.

Now, GSL uses the transformation x = (1-t)/t, to map onto interval (0,1].
So, for t<<0 is posible to get nan results since the behavior of your function tends to indeterminations (0/0 or inf/inf,etc) for extreme values.
Maybe if you write out the terms

Exp[ ( Ep(x) - \Mu)/T ] / { 1 + Exp[( Ep(x) - \Mu )/T] }^2

using A/B = Exp[ Ln A - Ln B], you could get a better numerical behavior.

I will try if and I have nice results, then I'll tell you.

**The solution**

As I said before, you must take care the problems arising with indeterminate forms. So, lets write out the problematic terms using the logarithmic version:

```
  double dIdmu(double x, void * parametros){
      double *p,Ep,mu,M,T;  
      p=(double *) parametros;

      M=p[0];
      T=p[1];
      mu=p[2];

      Ep=sqrt(x*x+M*M);

    double fplus= - ( exp( (Ep - mu)/T  -2.0*log(1.0 + exp((Ep - mu)/T) ) ) -  exp( (Ep + mu)/T  -2.0*log(1.0 + exp((Ep + mu)/T) ) ) )  * pow(x,2)   /  (2.*  T * Ep*pow(M_PI,2));

return fplus;
        }
```

and with this main function

```
    int main()
{
  double params[3];

  double resultTest2, error1Test2;

  gsl_integration_workspace * w 
    = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (10000);

  params[0]=0.007683; //M
  params[1]=0.284000;// T
  params[2]=0.1;   //mu

    gsl_function dI2mu_u; 
    dI2mu_u.function = &dIdmu;
    dI2mu_u.params = &params;
    gsl_integration_qagiu (&dI2mu_u, 0.0, 1e-7, 1e-7, 10000, w, &resultTest2, &error1Test2);


    printf("%e\n", resultTest2);
    gsl_integration_workspace_free ( w);

    return 0;
}
```

**you get the answer:
-5.065288e-03. 
I am curious... This is how I define the function in Mathematica**

[image]

So comparing the answers:

- GSL                   -5.065288e-03
- Mathematica           -0.005065287633739702

Comment: You might want to replace `log(1.0 + exp(...))` with `log1p(exp(...))`, as proposed in my answer. This should increase accuracy for small `x`.

Comment: I did not know about the log1p function. It will be quite useful in some of my algorithms. Thanks a lot for the suggestion @EOF.

Comment: I think that this will solve my problem, thank yo so much @YonatanZuletaOchoa for taking the time to help me.